# Custom Sort Order for MYSQL Count Results?

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am trying to write a report on some data I collected using a google form. Each person was asked how many of an item they had in their closet. I want to present the data as a count of how many out of the total fell into each range. So, I used this mysql query to count the instances of each answer:

```
SELECT  `Closet` , COUNT( * ) FROM  `TABLE 1` GROUP BY  `Closet`
```

And here is the resulting data:

```
Closet  | COUNT( * )
--------+------------
0       | 8
1-5     | 124
101-200 | 7
11-20   | 181
201-300 | 3
21-50   | 171
51-100  | 48
6-10    | 156
```

The problem is that alphabetically, 101-200 items sorts before 6-10 items. I basically want to sort this in some way that would put the number ranges in a logical order. (1-5, 6-10, 11-20, etc).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: the way your data is currently stored, makes it difficult to access in this way. instead of storing field closet as string, consider storing it in two fields ( closet_left and closet_right ) as integers which can be properly ordered

Comment: I collected info with a google form, and was expecting to just go through that data by hand because I was expecting about 50 responses. I have over 700 responses and doing it by hand is out. 

It's a terrible dataset for many reasons, but I now have 700 people interested in the results, so I need to do something to make this work.

Had I anticipated getting this large of a response, I would have coded a form and actually designed a database instead. It's a bad situation.

Comment: its ok to have a post scrape step to migrate this storage to a more accessible form. then when you access your data it should be simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `convert` & `substring_index`.

```
SELECT `Closet` , COUNT( * ) FROM `TABLE 1` GROUP BY `Closet` order by convert(substring_index(Closet,'-',1), unsigned integer)
```

This will sort the Closet by taking the first number of the ranges, which should essentially do the job.

Comment: A nifty function I did not know before! Your edit was not even necessary since `substring_index('0','-',1)` returns `0` already. +1